# scala api design: can i avoid either an unsafe cast or generics

Tags: scala

I am writing a library that provides a distributed algorithm. The idea being that existing applications can add the library to use the algorithm. The algorithm is in a library module and it abstracts the actual transmission of data over the network behind a trait. An application that uses the algorithm has to provide the actual network transport code. In code it looks something like the following:

```
// library is really a separate project not a single object
object Library {

  // handle to a remote server
  trait RemoteProcess

  // concrete server need to know how to actually send to a real remote process
  trait Server {
    def send(client: RemoteProcess, msg: String)
  }
}

// the application uses the library and provides the concrete transport
object AkkaDemoApplication {

  // concreate ref is a m wrapper to an actor ref in demo app
  case class ConcreteRemoteProcess(ref: akka.actor.ActorRef) extends Library.RemoteProcess

  class AkkaServer extends Library.Server {
    // **WARNING** this wont compile its here to make my question
    override def send(client: ConcreteRemoteProcess, msg: String): Unit = client.ref ! msg
  }
}
```

A couple of options I have considered:

1. Have the signature of the AkkaServer method overload the library trait method then perform an unsafe cast to ConcreteRemoteProcess. Yuk!
2. Have the signature of the AkkaServer method overload the library trait method then pattern match on the RemoteProcesss argument give a ConcreteRemoteProcess. This is no better than an unsafe cast in terms of blowing up at runtime if the wrong thing is passed.
3. Make the library server generic in terms of the RemoteProcess.

An example of option 3 looks like:

```
object Library {

  trait Server[RemoteProcess] {
    def send(client: RemoteProcess, msg: String)
  }
}

object Application {
  class AkkaServer extends Library.Server[ActorRef] {
    override def send(client: ActorRef, msg: String): Unit = client ! msg
  }
}
```

I tried option 3 and it worked but the generic type ended up be stamped on just about every type throughout the entire library module. There was then a lot of covariant and contravariant hassles to get the algorithmic code to compile. Simply to get compile time certainty at the one integration point the cognitive overhead was very large. Visually the library code is dominated by the generic signatures as though understanding that is critical to understanding the library when in fact it's a total distraction to understanding the library logic.

So using the genetic works and gave me compile time certainly but now I wished I had gone with the option 2 (the pattern match) with the excuse "it would fail fast at startup if someone got it wrong lets keep it simple".

Am I missing some Scala feature or idiom here to get compile time certainty without the cognitive overhead of a "high touch" generic that all the library code touches but ignores?

**Edit** I have considered that perhaps my code library is badly factored such that a refactor could move the generic to the boundaries. Yet the library has already been refactored for testability and that breakup into testable responsibilities is part of the problem of the generic getting smeared around the codebase. Hence my question is: in general is there another technique I don't know about to avoid a generic to provide a concrete implementation to an abstract API?

Comment: Will RemoteProcess always be a sub type of ActorRef?

Comment: No it won't always be an ActorRef. The open source project is the distributed consensus algorithm itself. The idea being that the algorithm library can be embeddable into existing applications which don't use actors.

Comment: Ugly but runnable code for the generic version is over at 
http://goo.gl/r4fZyJ press the execute button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are coupling your algorithm and Akka too closely. Further more, I assume the server to send data to the remote client that performs some operation and sends back the result

### Answer

Why not

```
object Library {
  // handle to a remote server
  trait RemoteProcessInput

  trait RemoteProcessResult

  // concrete server need to know how to actually send to a real remote process and how to deal with the result
  trait Server {
    def handle(clientData: RemoteProcessInput) : Future[RemoteProcessResult] 
  }
}
```

A concrete implementation provides the implementation with Akka

```
object Application {
  class AkkaServerImpl(system: ActorSystem)
  extends Library.Server {
    override def handle(clientData: RemoteProcessInput)
  : ActorRef, msg: String): Future[RemoteProcessResult] = {
      // send data to client and expect result
      // you can distinguish target and msg from the concrete input
      val ref : ActorRef = ??? // (resolve client actor)
      val msg = ??? // (create your message based on concrete impl)
      val result = ref ? msg // using ask pattern here
                             // alternatively have an actor living on server side that sends msgs and receives the clients results, triggered by handle method
      result
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: oops yes the library has both a send and a respond so the code fragment was mixed up. thanks for pointing that out it that fragment now compiles over at http://goo.gl/PcLP9B

Comment: and just to double check that it runs after it compiles this very convoluted version has a main that that code sharing engine will run that calls the method in an ugly way 
http://goo.gl/r4fZyJ

Comment: this is a great answer so i have +1. still mulling over the implications. thanks. deleted my first comment as it was not in the spirit of things. so thanks again.

Comment: executable code for this answer is over at http://goo.gl/PkT6ff click the execute button